# iOS5 GestureRecognizer fires only on the second tap

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

Would anyone have an idea why Tap gesture recognizer is called only after second tap in ios5, although in ios6 it works fine after one tap.

The code works in ios6, I tried this code also in separate project and works as well for ios5, I think it's linked to the project settings, but I cannot find out which.

My Code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = questTitle;
    //add coretextview
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    coreTextView = [[FTCoreTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 0)];
    coreTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    // set text
    [coreTextView setText:[self textForView]];
    // set styles
    [coreTextView addStyles:[self coreTextStyle]];
    // set delegate
    [coreTextView setDelegate:self];

    [coreTextView fitToSuggestedHeight];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = TRUE;

    [scrollView addSubview:coreTextView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(coreTextView.frame) + 40)];


     [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)];
tapGesture.delegate = (id <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
[coreTextView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;            // How many taps
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;


coreTextView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView.exclusiveTouch = NO;
scrollView.delegate = self;
[tapGesture release];


}


- (void)pan:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
     NSLog(@"Pan tap");
}



- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
      NSLog(@"tap");
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
      NSLog(@"tap");
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
      NSLog(@"tap");
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the code in question.

Comment: It's a little counter intuitive to name your tap gesture "panGesture" don't you think?

Comment: Looks better?) Do you think you could help me now?

Comment: Do you have by any chance another recognizer, e.g., to detect panning? Then, iOS can not distinguish which gesture just has started.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion Mathis...is there way to detect another gesture recognizer? I didn't define another one in my code though.

Comment: An `UIView` has a property `gestureRecognizers` that is an array of all `UIGestureRecognizer`s attached to this view. However, it may be possible that another view receive the touch, too.

Comment: Yes, there are other gesture recognizers on scroll view as well but why then it is working fine if i use this code in new project. In fact in all my screens of this project for ios5 i have this problem. Gestures is recognized only on second tap. Would you have an idea why it is like that?